# How to work with custom validator class for the whole page?

Tags: jsf-2

I've 3 text boxes (with `id`s say - A, B, C) in my form. And I've associated `f:validator validatorId="abc"` to one of my input text boxes (say for `id` - 'A') in my form.

Now the question is, can I get whatever values the user has entered for text boxes B & C within my validator class?

Also, is there any way that I can perform validations for the whole page in one shot in my validator class during submit, instead of associating `f:validator` to each component separately?

Comment: you can reuse the same validator for multiple inputs - just wrap the validator with the inputs , also take a look at this : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/multi-components-validator-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question **:** I have no idea about that.[Ask BalusC ;)]
For your first question **:** 
Yes, you can get the values of text boxes B & C.
To do that you have to pass those values as attributes of **text box A**.
See following example. Two attributes have been introduced to **text box A** and the values of   other text boxes have been assigned as the values of those attributes.

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText id="txtA">
    <f:validator validatorId="textValidator"/>
    <f:attribute name="attrib_textB" value="#{myBean.textB}"/>
    <f:attribute name="attrib_textC" value="#{myBean.textC}"/>
  </h:inputText>

  <h:inputText value="#{myBean.textB}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange"/>
  </h:inputText>

  <h:inputText value="#{myBean.textC}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange"/>
  </h:inputText>

  <a4j:commandButton value="Save"/>
</h:form>
```

Now in your validator class you can access those variables like this.

```
public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) throws ValidatorException {
    String textA = (String) arg2;//value of text box A
    String textB = (String) arg1.getAttributes().get("attrib_textB");//value of text box B
    String textC = (String) arg1.getAttributes().get("attrib_textC");//value of text box C
}
```

That's all. Note that my "**MyBean**" class has getter and setter methods for *textA* and *textB* string fields.

Comment: thanks prageeth. btw, shud I need to "bind" B and C components to 2 bean UIInput attributes?

Comment: That is not necessary in this case. However you can do it without any problem. Then access the values using `uiInput.getSubmittedValue()` method. The advantage of this method(binding) is you can access any attribute of **textBoxB** in your validator class.